# ExternalSecret referencing to AWS parameter store, updated value there only take effect after I delete my service pod, why?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

I have my backend service (`my-service`) which uses environment variables from AWS parameter store.

`my-service` manifest:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  ...
  ...
  spec:
    containers:
    - name: my-service
      image: my_service_image:latest
      ...
      envFrom:
        - secretRef:
              name: my-param-store
```

As you can see above, the `envFrom` section specified a secret reference named `my-param-store`, which is a AWS Parameter Store. Its manifest looks like this:

```
apiVersion: 'kubernetes-client.io/v1'
kind: ExternalSecret
metadata:
  name: my-param-store
spec:
  backendType: systemManager
  data:
    - key: /my-service/MY_SECRET
      name: MY_SECRET
```

After I deployed all these. My service is running fine. Then I want to see that if I change the value stored in AWS parameter store, my-service should not be able to handle request anymore.  To verify that I did the following:

**Step 1**. I changed the value of the key `/my-service/MY_SECRET` in AWS parameter store. I expect my service would fail to handle request, but it still handle requests successfully.  I was thinking "Hmm... probably I should manually delete that `my-param-store` object & create a new one so that the new value in AWS parameter store would start take effect.

**Step 2**. So, I `kubectl delete externalsecret my-param-store`. Then I deployed again, the new external secret object is created in cluster.

**Step 3**. Then, I tried again sending request to my-service, I expect this time it should fail to handle request, but NO, my-service still can handle request successfully.

**Step 4**. Finally, I decided to delete my-service pod (`kubectl delete pod my-service-58fb12`). After did that, k8s spin up a new my-service pod.  And this time my-service indeed failed at handling request due to the value in AWS parameter store was changed.

**My question is,** Why should I delete my-service pod in order to have the new value in AWS parameter store starts taking effect? I mean why it doesn't take effect after I deleted `my-param-store` & created a new one(in step 2)? What is the mechanism of k8s behind that makes only deleting my-service pod would have the new value of key in AWS parameter store take effect in my case?

Answer (score 0):

> ... uses environment variables from AWS parameter store.
>
> envFrom:
>
> - secretRef:
>   name: my-param-store
>
> As you can see above, the envFrom section specified a secret reference
> named my-param-store

Environment variable created from secret resource will not be updated when the secret changed. See the official [note](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#consuming-secret-values-from-environment-variables) here.

Comment: Thanks, I try to link your answer with my question, still don't feel it answered my question.  I am not using volume for secret, as said I am using AWS Parameter Store as an external secret.  My question is to understand the behaviour of k8s in my case, why re-creating external secret object doesn't reflect the updated value in AWS parameter store in the service pod until I also re-created the service pod.

Comment: The environment variable referencing a secret once created **will not be** updated by K8s, regardless whether the secret is managed by secret CSI (eg. external secret) that referencing ssm parameter store or secret manager. When the pod is re-deployed, environment variable in the new pod will get re-created with the secret value at that point in time.

Comment: if I translated to other words, you mean every time I updated the value in AWS parameter store I need to delete application pod & re-deploy again?

Comment: Correct. Alternately, you can use secret volume to receive update without restarting the workload.